# Full Text Search Like in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

How we can do Full Text Search in InnoDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InnoDB doesn't natively support full-text search. You can use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) to accomplish something similar to this though, I believe.

Comment: ah! But then one waits and comes back the day after! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Innodb doesnt support full text searching, if you really need full text searching then what you can do is have a duplicate mysiam table of the original innodb table and have your full text search done on the duplicate table

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 5.6 Innodb full text search FTS facility provided.

Answer (score 0):

**[Fulltext seach is MyISAM only.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't. InnoDB does not support fulltext indexes.

> Full-text indexes can be used only
>   with MyISAM tables, and can be created
>   only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT
>   columns.
>   From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to this thread, `MySql 5.6` now supports `FULLTEXT` indexes in innoDb :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is outdated, InnoDB supported fulltext search already in MySQL 5.6, check [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/26/myisam-vs-innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-1/) for more information